# CUDA: GPUDirect on GeForce GTX 690

Tags: cuda, nvidia, gpudirect

The GeForce GTX 690 (from vendors like Zotac and EVGA) can be used for CUDA programming, much like a Tesla K10.

Question: Does the GeForce GTX 690 support GPUDirect? 
Specifically: If I were to use two GTX 690 cards, I would have 4 GPUs (two GPUs within each card). If I connect both GTX 690 cards to the same PCIe switch, will GPUDirect work well for communication between any pair of the 4 GPUs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

According to the requirements stated [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#multi-device-system) it is necessary to have Tesla series GPUs.  So GeForce devices are not officially supported for GPUDirect Peer-to-Peer.:

"When the application is run as a 64-bit process on Windows Vista/7 in TCC mode (see Tesla Compute Cluster Mode for Windows), on Windows XP, or on Linux, devices of compute capability 2.0 and higher **from the Tesla series** may address each other’s memory (i.e., a kernel executing on one device can dereference a pointer to the memory of the other device). This peer-to-peer memory access feature is supported between two devices if cudaDeviceCanAccessPeer() returns true for these two devices. "

Comment: anecdotally, I have heard from a colleague that they were able to get GPUDirect Peer to Peer working between the two GPUs on GTX690.

Answer (score 0):

This blog might be of help ... [NVIDIA Hardware Comparison – GeForce GTX 690 vs. Tesla K10][1]

http://www.acceleware.com/blog/nvidia-hardware-comparison-%E2%80%93-geforce-gtx-690-vs-tesla-k10

Answer (score 0):

According to [NVidia's NVIDIA GPUDirect page](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpudirect)

> GPUDirect  peer-to-peer transfers and memory access are supported natively by the CUDA Driver. All you need is CUDA Toolkit v4.0 and R270 drivers (or later) and a system with two or more Fermi- or Kepler-architecture GPUs on the same PCIe bus.